# Convert series of images into an array using OpenCV and convert the RGB array to gray scale

Tags: python, arrays, image, opencv, rgb

Hi I'm trying to convert a series of images into an array and then convert the RGB to gray scale.

In my work folder I have x number of frames.png, I need to read all this frames in an array and then convert each frame (RGB) to Gray scale.

For one frame my code is:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2 as cv
from PIL import Image

# Read image

Image = cv.imread('frame0.png') 


# RGB to Gray Scale

GS = cv.cvtColor(Image, cv.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
th, Gray = cv.threshold(GS, 128, 192, cv.THRESH_OTSU)
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use os to read files from a folder. With the "endswith" function, you can extract file formats and pull them all.

Here is a working code

```
import numpy as np
import cv2 as cv
import os

for file in os.listdir("/mydir"): # images folder path
    if file.endswith((".png",".jpg")): # you can add formats
        img = cv.imread(file)
        GS = cv.cvtColor(img, cv.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
        th, Gray = cv.threshold(GS, 128, 192, cv.THRESH_OTSU)
        cv.imwrite("converted-"+file,Gray)
```

Comment: Thank you, I have a question: Can I save all this new files (cv.imwrite("converted-"+file,Gray)) in variables, and then operate them?

Comment: I guess I don't quite understand it, but it doesn't make sense to assign them all to different variables. You can read the image you will use with "cv.imread()".